# Why is Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory returning incorrect path?

Tags: android

I am trying to download fonts using WebView and DoanloadManager. I set the download folder directory as "Fonts" folder, using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Fonts/"` but I is creating a different unwanted directory instead, `sdcard/storage/emulated/0/Fonts/`. What is wrong with my code? Here is the full snippet:

```
 @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
            String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(filename);
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Fonts/", filename);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Are you running your code on an emulator instead of a real device?

Answer (score 0):

`sdcard/storage/emulated/0/` is path that is normally returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` when you are using an emulator.

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` can return any folder and you can't really anticipate the path. Today we have multiple profiles on the same device. Also, this can change based on the android API version.

Comment: What do you mean by API version? It always returned the expected path on my galaxy s7 android 7. I did update android studio though.

Comment: With different Api versions, new features are being brought in. Like multiple user accounts in a single mobile. Here, `getExternalStorageDirectory()` will return a different path for different user. That is why you can never hardcode the value returned by `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. The user may have sdcard, or internal storage and external storage path is impacted by this. Why do you care what location is returned by the method? The system returns the best possible path.